# Stop one of click events on the same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, preventdefault

I've button, with two click events on it.
What I'm trying to do is to prevent both or all events on that button dependent on a criteria.

I tried to use `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` and `return false;` but nothing works as I need.

```js
/* I need to stop $('button') event if the if condition
inside $('#btn') event passed */

$('#btn').click(function(e){
  var term = $('#term').val();

  if(term != '') {
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
    alert(2);
  } else {
    // continue
  }
});

$('button').click(function(e){
  alert(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="term" type="text" placeholder="type here ..">
<button type="button" id="btn">Check</button>
```

[JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1L8oevo4/1/)

Comment: You cannot put any code after the `return;` When you set `return` nothing below that line will be processed. Even throwing errors at you. That's why you cannot see your `alert(2)`.

Comment: You can't stop the second event handler , especially if it gets registered first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to stop both events. If so you should add clause to your $('button').click() handler.
First, in the $('#btn').click() handler add property to check if event should stop:

```
if(term != '') {
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    this.stop = 1;
...
```

Then check it:

```
  if (this.getAttribute("id") !== "btn" || this.stop !==1) {
      alert(1);
  }
```

Here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1L8oevo4/4/)

Comment: `this.getAttribute("id")` AKA `this.id`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan of course, because the if statement not passed

Comment: @user3003810 in that case it **should** alert 1! So follow this steps: 1. **without** entering any text click the button: `alert 1` will be thrown. 2. enter some text and click the button: nothing is alerted! (great so far). 3. remove the text and hit the button: `alert 1` should be thrown but **nothing happens**!

Comment: Somewhere have to be placed `this.stop = 0;`, e.g. after // continue comment.

Answer (score 1):

To break out of your function use only `return;` (instead of `return false;`)

Also, you cannot set any code after a `return` so here you go:

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var term = $.trim( $('#term').val() );

  if(term !== "") {
    alert("Value exists! I'm breaking any further operations.");
    return; // "Exit" my function
    // YOU CANNOT WRITE CODE AFTER A RETURN STATEMENT!
  } else { // Else is actually not needed but it's cool to have it for clearance
    alert("Value is empty.");
  }
});

$('button').click(function(e){
  alert(1); // You'll see this in any case.
});
```

---

To expand on your question **How to prevent the alert(1) from popping**

```js
$('#btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  this.term = $.trim( $('#term').val() );

  if(this.term) {
    alert("Value exists!");
  } else {
    alert("Value is empty.");
  }
});

$('button').click(function(e){
  if(!this.term) {
    alert(1); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="term" type="text" placeholder="type here ..">
<button type="button" id="btn">Check</button>
```

Comment: you missed understand me, I don't need to add any code inside if condition, what I need is if the term !== "", the second event which call alert(1); to be stopped !

Comment: @user3003810 you cannot AFAIK (without using a boolean flag). It's already too late since the listener is set and triggered *almost* simultaneously with the other `$("#btn")` click. So even if you use `$(this).off()` will not stop the alert(1) from yelling at you.

Comment: @user3003810 that's why I wrote *`" // You'll see this in any case."`*

Comment: @user3003810 but if I guess right you don't have control over the `alert(1)` function, right?... otherwise you could use a flag.

Comment: Hummm, so the only approach to do is create function with callback with if statement and call it second click event.

Comment: @user3003810 sure that's one way. The other is to use a *"flag"* boolean variable that toggles true/false, and you check inside the other (`'button` click) function for that variable.

Comment: @user3003810 expandeed my answer to account for that one too.